# Using Concatenation Within a CONTAINS Predicate (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to use concatenation within a `CONTAINS` predicate so I am able to use a variable; however, I am getting the error:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @search varchar;
SET @search = 'blue dude';

SELECT distinct itemno, basedescription,upc,CAST((SELECT [UNITPRICE] 
FROM PPPLTD.dbo.[ICPRICP] WHERE [ITEMNO] = replace([DataWarehouse].[dbo].[ORDERFORMDUMP].[ITEMNO],'-','') 
AND [PRICELIST] = (select top 1 priclist from PPPLTD.dbo.ARCUS 
where IDCUST = (select top 1 CUSTID from PPPLTD.dbo.WEBLOGINACCESS where [USER] = 'user')) 
and [CURRENCY] = 'CDN' 
and DPRICETYPE = 1) AS DECIMAL(18,2)),caseqty 
FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[ORDERFORMDUMP] 
where (allowinbc = 'Yes' or allowinab = 'Yes') 
and (contains(*, '"'+replace(@search,' ','" and "')+'"') 
or (select top 1 1 from PPPLTD.dbo.ICITEMO where OPTFIELD like 'UPC%' 
and VALUE like '%'+@search+'%' and ITEMNO = DataWarehouse.dbo.ORDERFORMDUMP.itemno) is not null) 
order by ORDERFORMDUMP.BASEDESCRIPTION
```

The query runs fine when I have `contains(*, ' "blue" and "dude" ')`

Also, I'm not sure if I'm able to use the `REPLACE` function in there. I need it to be able to replace white space with "**and**."

Using the `LIKE` keyword instead of `CONTAINS` is not an option for me.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you need the extra '"' - you should get a string out of the replace function. Also, you can try using CONCAT instead of plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically trying to use Dynamic SQL and T-SQL in one statement, which you cannot do.

You would need to create the SQL dynamically, then execute the sql text

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);
DECLARE @cond varchar(max)
DECLARE @search varchar(max);
SET @search = 'blue dude';
SET @cond = replace(@search,' ','" and "');
SET @sql = 'SELECT distinct itemno, basedescription,upc,CAST((SELECT [UNITPRICE] FROM PPPLTD.dbo.[ICPRICP] WHERE [ITEMNO] = replace([DataWarehouse].[dbo].[ORDERFORMDUMP].[ITEMNO],''-'','''') AND [PRICELIST] = (select top 1 priclist from PPPLTD.dbo.ARCUS where IDCUST = (select top 1 CUSTID from PPPLTD.dbo.WEBLOGINACCESS where [USER] = ''user'')) and [CURRENCY] = ''CDN'' and DPRICETYPE = 1) AS DECIMAL(18,2)),caseqty FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[ORDERFORMDUMP] where (allowinbc = ''Yes'' or allowinab = ''Yes'') '
SET @sql = @sql + 'and (contains(*, ''"' + @cond + '"'') '
SET @sql = @sql + 'or (select top 1 1 from PPPLTD.dbo.ICITEMO where OPTFIELD like ''UPC%'' and VALUE like ''%' + @search + '%'''
SET @sql = @sql + 'and ITEMNO = DataWarehouse.dbo.ORDERFORMDUMP.itemno) is not null) order by ORDERFORMDUMP.BASEDESCRIPTION'

print @sql -- This will help you see the actual resulting text for testing
EXECUTE (@sql)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I'm getting an error saying that the string inside @sql "**is not a valid identifier**"

Comment: see if adding parentheses around @sql as I did above helps

Comment: I also removed the extra 1 in the last set @sql statement

Comment: That got rid of the invalid identifier error. Now I'm getting an error: "**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.**" and I don't know which 'from' is causing the problem.

Comment: I didn't notice that @search was used multiple times, and the 'select top 1 1 'was not a mistake, I updated my answer